# capturing the value in html using selenium ide

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

I have the below code in the html

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var myValues={myName:'tester',DOB:'01-01-2013',location:'UK'};
</script>
```

How can i capture the value of myName i.e tester

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String sgVal = (String) js.executeScript("return myValues[myName];");
```

should work (untested).